# separating a list into two lists

Tags: python, list

I have this array:

`[160, 177], [162, 169], [163, 169], [166, 173], [166, 176], [166, 177], [169, 176], [169, 177]]`

How can I split it into 2 separate arrays so it becomes:

`[160,162,163,166,166,166,169,169]`

and

`[177,169,169,173,176,177,176,177]`

Comment: [I chose a duplicate at random.]

Comment: based on what condition do you seperate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it

```
l = [[160, 177], [162, 169], [163, 169], [166, 173], [166, 176], [166, 177], [169, 176], [169, 177]]
l1, l2 = zip(*l)
```