# reversing the tuples in a list

Tags: python, list

I have this list:

`[(3, 28), (25, 126), (25, 127), (26, 59)]`

How can I turn it into this:

`[(28, 3), (126, 25), (127, 25), (59, 26)]`

I just want to reverse what is in the tuple

Comment: Are you going to try to write any of this project yourself? Or are you just going to have StackOverflow write [every](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152957/separating-a-list-into-two-lists) [piece](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162525/list-of-strings-into-a-list-of-tuples-of-ints) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> lst = [(3, 28), (25, 126), (25, 127), (26, 59)]
>>> [i[::-1] for i in lst]
[(28, 3), (126, 25), (127, 25), (59, 26)]
```

`[::-1]` uses the [slice syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/1907098) to reverse the container preceding it. Note this will only work with containers where the slice syntax is supported.

Answer (score 7):

If you know the tuples will only be of length 2:

```
[(b, a) for a, b in lst]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a slice with a step of -1

```
>>> [x[::-1] for x in [(3, 28), (25, 126), (25, 127), (26, 59)]]
[(28, 3), (126, 25), (127, 25), (59, 26)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> L =  [(3, 28), (25, 126), (25, 127), (26, 59)]
>>> [(i[1], i[0]) for i in L]
```

may be **useful just** for two element.

Comment: much uglier than `[(b, a) for a, b in L]`

Answer (score 0):

Funny alternative

```
>>> L = [(3, 28), (25, 126), (25, 127), (26, 59)]
>>> zip(*zip(*L)[::-1])
[(28, 3), (126, 25), (127, 25), (59, 26)]
```

Or for some evil premature optimization:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> L = [(3, 28), (25, 126), (25, 127), (26, 59)]
>>> map(itemgetter(slice(None, None, -1)), L)
[(28, 3), (126, 25), (127, 25), (59, 26)]
```

Timings:

```
python -m timeit -s "L = [(3, 28), (25, 126), (25, 127), (26, 59)
]" "[i[::-1] for i in L]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.21 usec per loop   

python -m timeit -s "L = [(3, 28), (25, 126), (25, 127), (26, 59)
]" "zip(*zip(*L)[::-1])"
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.26 usec per loop   

python -m timeit -s "L = [(3, 28), (25, 126), (25, 127), (26, 59)
]; from operator import itemgetter;" "map(itemgetter(slice(None, None, -1)), L)"    
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.69 usec per loop

python -m timeit -s "L = [(3, 28), (25, 126), (25, 127), (26, 59)
]*100" "[i[::-1] for i in L]"
10000 loops, best of 3: 87.4 usec per loop

python -m timeit -s "L = [(3, 28), (25, 126), (25, 127), (26, 59)
]*100" "zip(*zip(*L)[::-1])"
10000 loops, best of 3: 67.1 usec per loop

python -m timeit -s "L = [(3, 28), (25, 126), (25, 127), (26, 59)
]*100;from operator import itemgetter;" "map(itemgetter(slice(None, None, -1)),
L)"
10000 loops, best of 3: 66.1 usec per loop

python -m timeit -s "L = [(3, 28), (25, 126), (25, 127), (26, 59)
]*100000" "[i[::-1] for i in L]"
10 loops, best of 3: 108 msec per loop

python -m timeit -s "L = [(3, 28), (25, 126), (25, 127), (26, 59)
]*100000" "zip(*zip(*L)[::-1])"
10 loops, best of 3: 109 msec per loop

python -m timeit -s "L = [(3, 28), (25, 126), (25, 127), (26, 59)
]*100000;from operator import itemgetter;" "map(itemgetter(slice(None, None, -1)
), L)"
10 loops, best of 3: 82.9 msec per loop
```

Comment: @Volatility funnily enough it's not even shorter than the list comp. However it produces some interesting timings... I will post them soon

Comment: Actually it wasn't that funny but I posted some timings showing the fastest ways to do it. The double `zip` slows down quick on huge data